# How to add script tags dynamically in index.html page of the angular 5+ project?

Tags: angular, typescript

Where I can add any script tags dynamically, by getting server side response.

Comment: You don't. That's not the purpose of a single page application : if you have to load your JS dynamically, consider using languages such as PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your exact use case. But sometimes we need to load some script which is required in some workflows ONLY, instead of downloading unnecessarily.

For example 
I have a banking app and I need to load payment-gateway SDK only in a few scenarios. So whenever that part of the code is executed than at that time I used the javascript function

```
_loadScript(scriptSrcUrl, onLoadSuccessCallback, onErrorCallback) {
  if (scriptSrcUrl)
    if (document.querySelector('script[src="' + scriptSrcUrl + '"]')) {
      onLoadSuccessCallback();
    } else {
      var a = document.createElement('script');
      a.setAttribute('async', ''),
        (a.src = scriptSrcUrl),
        onLoadSuccessCallback && (a.onload = onLoadSuccessCallback),
        onErrorCallback && (a.onerror = onErrorCallback),
        document.head.appendChild(a);
    }
}

_scriptLoaded(result) {
    if(result) {
        // use the script
    } else {
        // handleError
    }
}


lazyLoadScriptsInDom() {
    this._loadScript(
        "https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js",
        this._scriptLoaded.bind(this, !0),
        this._scriptLoaded.bind(this, !1)
    );
}
```